# Is there any rule that there should always be an article before a singular, uncountable, and common noun?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

Sentence is -

> For a long time, paracetamol has been recommended as a first-line drug in pain management guidelines.

On Google, I found that "paracetamol" is a common noun and is also a singular countable. So, why can’t I use an article before it? Is it something like when a singular common noun is used in a general sense, we do not use any article?

[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8347233/)

Comment: *On Google, I found that "paracetamol" is a common noun and is also a sinular countable.* It would help if you explained where you saw this so we can judge whether it's trustworthy or if you've misunderstood (and also spelt singular correctly if that's what you meant).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paracetamol is the name of a substance, and is normally non-countable.  As a non-count noun it doesn't use a singular article, or have a plural form.

It does have a countable sense, meaning "a single tablet containing paracetamol"  In this sense "a paracetamol" is correct.

> I had a headache so I took a paracetamol and lay down.  (one tablet)

> If you take paracetamol you should not drink alcohol.  (an amount)

> How much paracetamol did you take? (amount) How many paracetamols did you take? (number of tablets)

This is the same as "I drink coffee" and "I drank a coffee", where the latter means "one cup of coffee".

You would use a definite article, when the question "Which paracetamol?" can be answered:

> I had some asprin and paracetamol in my cupboard, but I threw the paracetamol away, because it was out of date.  (uncountable but with a definite article in the second use because it has been definitely identified by the first use)

Comment: Can I put "the" before paracetamol in the same sentence?- For a long time, paracetamol has been recommended as a first-line drug in pain management guidelines.

Comment: No, because it isn't definite (you can't answer the question "which paracetamol?"). So no definite article

Comment: Secondly, is there something like when a singular, countable common noun is used in a general sense, we do not use any article?

Comment: When it is non-count you don't use an indefinite article.  A common use of non-count nouns is to name substances.  "coffee", "wood", "iron", "water" are all (usually) non-count nouns that name substances.

Comment: No, because it isn't definite (you can't answer the question "which paracetamol?"). So no definite article. If I have the answer or if I have to say or indicate towards a particular paracetamol, can I use "the"? Example: The paracetamol that you eat had adverse effects.

Comment: Can I say, I drank a water (a cup of water)?

Comment: That's rare, but possible. It's More likely if the drink is in some way special, but water is not very special.  However, "I drank a beer" or "I drank a coffee" is sometimes used.  But you are now asking new questions that are not about paracetamol.

Comment: "The paracetamol that you **ate**" refers to a particular dose of the drug.

Comment: If you are experiencing a side-effect from taking paracetamol, it would be idiomatic for someone to tell you "That's *the* paracetamol."  It would mean "That reaction is an effect of *the paracetamol you have taken*". The definite article there is licensed by "(that) you have taken" which is implicit in "That's the paracetamol".

Comment: @AryenduKumar It's not idiomatic to say "**people *eat* medicine**" unless you're of the belief that raw vegetables and the like can heal certain illnesses, in which case they require chewing. It's much more usual to say **I *took* a paracetamol** or **People *take paracetamol* for aches, flu, fevers etc**

Comment: @JamesK One more question that I would like to ask. It is necessary to use an article "the" before uncountable abstract noun or is it upto me ? Example : The association of the official group of college and university. Can I omit "the" before association to make a general sense ?

Comment: You use "the" when it is necessary.  But please ask new unrelated questions in a new question.